# Can't access os.environ in Django Settings

Tags: python, django, environment-variables

I have those lines of code in my Django App

```
import os
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'noodles',
        'USER': 'khophi',
        'PASSWORD': os.environ['DB_PASSWORD'], # I have this part in my system environment. I can verify
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

How do I verify that a variable exists in my terminal:

```
import os
os.environ['DB_PASSWORD'] # returns the value stored in there
```

When I call the same value via Django settings, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 303, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 48, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 44, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 92, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/noodles/Noodles/settings.py", line 117, in <module>
    'PASSWORD': os.environ['DB_PASSWORD'],
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 23, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'DB_PASSWORD'
```

I added the values to my `~/.pam_environment`. The server is running within the same user as the `~/.pam_environment`.

Why can't I get access to the os.environ values?

Edit: I've seen how the environment variables are exposed to the Django settings, but they apply for apache mod_wsgi. Can I do something similar for django-nginx-gunicorn ?

Comment: I had this issue when celery etc run as a different user. Why don't you try something like https://github.com/theskumar/python-dotenv ?

Comment: @GlynJackson I'm checking now

Comment: @GlynJackson Okay I went through the codes. Couldn't find anything as basic as possible to expose the os.environ to the settings file. Please explain how I could achieve that.

Comment: @Rexford this is a common pattern and countless django devs use os.environ directly in settings (as do I). This is a difficult question to answer as it relates to your particular environment. I've certainly had issues with uWSG not setting envvars for django (as an example of a server config problem). Issues with envvars passing to a python app is a common problem.

Comment: For Apache at least, environment variables set for a user account are not inherited by your code, even if Apache or mod_wsgi was told to run as that user. You would need to set environment variables at the start of the WSGI script file.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Having the values in the wsgi will defeat the whole idea of why I want the values in the server. The values are credentials that shouldn't be a part of my commits to git. Yes I can ignore those files and sftp onto the server for production without touching git, however I don't wanna do that. I want to values to BE in the system either in nginx or gunicorn or wherever aside my project code.

Comment: You don't need to have them in the WSGI file. They just need to be set in the WSGI file. Read the key/values from a file under /etc and set os.environ using that.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Okay, I get it. Thanks. Will try that.